# Why I got this MySql Error on update sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table like.

```
 CREATE TABLE `chart` (
      `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `item` char(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `IsLeaf` char(1) NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
      `ParentId` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   )
```

**Where parentId contains an id of another row , which is the parent of that row**
Like

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   Id  |   item    |   IsLeaf      |  ParentId
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   1   |   Test1   |   D           |  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   2   |   Test3   |   D           |  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   3   |   Test4   |   D           |   1
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   4   |   Test5   |   D           |   1
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to update those rows which have at least one child row. I tried like this

```
UPDATE chart AS c1 SET c1.IsLeaf='Y' JOIN chart c2 ON c2.ParentId=c1.id;
```

and got this error

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN chart c2 ON c2.ParentId=c1.id' at line 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use SET KEYWORD after LEFT JOIN and have to check null

```
UPDATE chart AS c1 
LEFT JOIN chart c2 ON c2.ParentId=c1.id SET c1.IsLeaf='Y' 
WHERE c2.id is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `LEFT JOIN` like this:-

```
 UPDATE chart AS c1 
 LEFT JOIN chart c2 ON c2.ParentId=c1.id 
 SET c1.IsLeaf='Y' WHERE c2.id is null;
```